# How do I create a MAXIF statement on a UserForm in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, max, userform

I have tried to do this with a couple different functions, but I am thinking a MAXIF statement is actually my best route. My goal is to have a textbox value equal the result from a maxif formula running from a worksheet. To give a rather choppy example of this, the formula would be something like this:

```
SalesForm.BHSDRECORDTD.Value = Max(If(Worksheets("TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (4.18.23)").Range("F:F")=SalesForm.BHSDMAINNUMBERLF.Value, Worksheets("TELEDATA IN PROGRESS (4.18.23)").Range("C:C"))
```

Upon simply trying this, I'm realizing that MAX is not a vba function. How do I translate this properly?

Comment: Use `Application.WorksheetFunction`.

Comment: @JosWoolley wow, I was truly overthinking this. `Application.WorksheetFunction.MaxIfs` was it.